# Are there single-words (or at least within 5 words) for or that describes "The need to find and right your misjudgment of a person"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for single-words for or that describe "The need to find and 
right, your misjudgment of a person". I need this because I'm writing a
script and in a scene, I'm having a group of people who misjudged, had 
misassumption of, cast out and mistreated (etc, words with the idea that
"information that was assumed to be correct but ended up being false") a
character.

> This Character is male

And an eventually they realized their wrongs and that they were wrong about
him, and now they want to apologize and tell him they were wrong to judge
and assume who he was. And they were wrong to cast him out and wrong to
mistreat him, but it was too late, the character ran away because of the 
actions and assumptions made against him by the group of people.

And now the group of people is searching for him, in hopes to apologize
and tell him that they realized what they were doing was wrong and have him 
come back home.

Are there any single-words for these feelings, actions, or needs, describe in one word?

> The need to find this person, to apologize, and to explain and right their wrongs and have them come back home.

I need this single-word to describe them and when I say *"them"* I refer to
the group of people previously describe in most of the text above.

Comment: You're question is unclear.  In several places you say you're looking for a word that means "a/the need to...," which would be a noun, but then you also say that the single word you need is "to describe them," which would be an adjective.  So, you need to decide what it is you're looking for.  Also, if you're looking for a word that conveys one or more paragraphs of meaning, you're not going to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The need to right the wrong you have done someone:

**atone**, verb

> make amends or reparation.
>
> "he was being helpful, to atone for his past mistakes"
>
> synonyms:  make amends, make reparation, make restitution, make recompense, make redress, make up for, compensate, pay, pay the penalty, pay the price, recompense, answer; expiate, make good, offset; do penance, redeem oneself, redress the balance;
>
> "what would you have me do to atone for my sin?"
>
> From Oxford

Answer (score 0):

**[repent](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/repent)** (Cambridge Dictionary)

(Verb)

> to be very sorry for something bad you have done in the past and
>   wish that you had not done it.

("Repent" is the word comes into my mind, but I am not sure whether this word is suitable to cover the OP's meaning "The/A need to find" part.)